# Linux Device Tree GPIO Interrupt

Tags: linux, kernel, interrupt, device-tree

I have an I2C accelerometer chip that I am trying to interface to AM335X processor running Linux 3.12 kernel.

I have set up my device tree this way but it doesn't seem to have hooked up the interrupt sources correctly. My driver (http://www.st.com/web/en/catalog/tools/PF258114) does not receive any interrupts.

```
i2c1: i2c@4802a000 {
        status = "okay";
        pinctrl-names = "default";
        pinctrl-0 = <&i2c1_pins>;

        clock-frequency = <100000>;

        accel: accel@19 {
                /* compatible="st,lis3lv02d" */
                compatible="st,lis2dh";
                interrupt-parent = <&gpio0>;
                interrupts = < 22 0x01 >;
                reg = <0x19>;
        };
};
```

My chip is at address 19.

My GPIO interrupt line is GPIO 0-22 and it is an active high

When I insmod the driver it starts up and sets up the hardware but does nothing else:

```
# insmod /mnt/rootfs/lis2dh_acc.ko
[   38.351272] lis2dh_acc accelerometer driver: init
[   38.362857] lis2dh_acc 1-0019: probe start.
[   38.367291] lis2dh_acc 1-0019: using default plaform_data
[   38.382664] lis2dh_acc: hw init start
[   38.392011] lis2dh_acc: hw init done
[   38.402053] input: lis2dh_acc as /devices/ocp.2/4802a000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0019/input/input1
[   38.415506] lis2dh_acc 1-0019: lis2dh_acc: probed
[   38.429872] i2c-core: driver [lis2dh_acc] using legacy suspend method
[   38.442815] i2c-core: driver [lis2dh_acc] using legacy resume method
```

I even force a "1" into enable_device:

echo 1 > /sys/devices/ocp.2/4802a000.i2c/i2c-1/1-0019/input/input1/device/enable_device

but still nothing.

Can anybody help me figure out if my device tree is incorrectly set up? or what could be the issue?

Thanks